# Loading module installed directly from github repo with npm

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install

I installed a public github repo using the syntax provided in the repository's readme:

```
npm install https://github.com/user_name/proj_name.git
```

However, I'm not sure how to load this module into my js code. I've tried:

```
const my_lib = 'proj_name';
```

Unfortunately, this is not working for me. How can I load a module that was installed directly from a github repository?

Comment: What name is provided in the `package.json` file in that repo?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, it is the same as proj_name in the github url

Comment: Check your dependencies in `package.json` file and import module with `const my_lib = require('package_name')`

Comment: @AhmetZeybek, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: For example, if you added expressjs with `yarn add expressjs/express`, this would be seen in package.json as `express`, so you can import this module with `const express = require('express')`

Comment: Does it work for you? `const my_lib = require('proj_name');`

Comment: No, it doesn't unfortunately

Comment: Could you share the repo URL? It would be easier to try it out and tell what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're just defining a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) as a string with value `'proj_name'`.
To load a module from `node_modules`, you have to do the following:

`npm install <package_name> --save`, where `--save` write the package and version in your dependencies of `package.json`. You can also use `--savedev` to write the package in your devDependencies *(both optional)*.

Use `const packageName = require('packageName');` in your e.g. `app.js` to use the package in your code.

See here for more details about [npm install in general](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), [specifying-dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) and here for [ecma script require and import](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_require).

Comment: This was helpful. I didn't realize I needed to add the --save flag. It's worth noting that I don't have a full node app/project setup. I just had a single script that I was trying to run that was requiring that package.